# Normal calculation and comparation of points, how to perform this?

Tags: ros, pcl, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem do you know how to estimate a normal for a single point using the function:

computePointNormal (const pcl::PointCloud &cloud, const std::vector &indices, Eigen::Vector4f &plane_parameters, float &curvature);

How can I fill the indices?

After the normal calculation how can I compare two normals of different points and check if their pointing directions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224209/normal-calculation-and-comparation-of-points,-how-to-perform-this?/) by [Nxzx](https://answers.ros.org/users/25604/nxzx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2016-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is more like a [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/) question. Though I can give some insight.

As it is told in pcl tutorial [Normal Estimation](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation.php),

> To compute a single point normal, use:
>
> ```
> computePointNormal (const pcl::PointCloud<PointInT> &cloud, const std::vector<int> &indices, Eigen::Vector4f &plane_parameters, float &curvature);
> ```
>
> Where cloud is the input point cloud
> that contains the points, indices
> represents the set of k-nearest
> neighbors from cloud, and
> plane_parameters and curvature
> represent the output of the normal
> estimation, with plane_parameters
> holding the normal (nx, ny, nz) on the
> first 3 coordinates, and the fourth
> coordinate is D = nc . p_plane
> (centroid here) + p.

To be able to estimate a normal for a single point you need to use neighbouring points to estimate a surface. Without those you can not have a normal for a point. For those neighbouring points you should use a method like [kNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm). In PCL we have kNN implementation with [KdTree Class](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_kd_tree.html).

Depending on your application you can use `KdTree` to gather k-nearest neighbour points to your target point for normal estimation. Then, you should supply indices of those points to `computePointNormal` method. For usage of `KdTree`, you can check [this tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/kdtree_search.php).

Hope this helps. For further questions you can visit [pcl-users.org](http://www.pcl-users.org/).

**Update**

About your code in your answer,
`computePointNormal` waits `const pcl::PointCloud<PointInT> &cloud` as first argument, but you are passing point cloud pointer. Possibly it will be fine if you change it to this (Note the `*` );

```
computePointNormal(*filteredCloud1,pointIdxRadiusSearch,plane_parameters,curvature);
```

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nxzx](https://answers.ros.org/users/25604/nxzx/) on 2016-01-21**:
Thank you! It is working now!

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-01-21**:
Glad you made it! Then you can mark this answer as accepted so that future users will use the same solution with you.

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2018-08-08**:
Sir, do you mind taking a look at this post? Thank you.
https://answers.ros.org/question/300085/camera-recommendation-used-for-depth-measurement/